# ¿Cómo agregar una fecha con datetime?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de StackOverflow ,cómo puedo agregar la fecha y hora usando strftime? necesito ingresar la fecha `07-05-1990 12:30` en UT.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import datetime 
x = 07-05-1990 12:30
fecha = datetime(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print('La fecha es {0}'.format(fecha))
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: La fecha "07-05-1990 12:30" la recibes como cadena de algún sitio, o es una fecha prefijada? Porque si es lo segundo puedes hacer `x = datetime.datetime(1990, 5, 7, 12, 30)` (y después simplemente `fecha = x.strftime(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

[Acá](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) he encontrado el formato para extraer una fecha desde un `string`:

```
%Y: Year (4 digits)
%m: Month
%d: Day of month
%H: Hour (24 hour)
%M: Minutes
%S: Seconds
%f: Microseconds
```

Lo que hace falta es el método `datetime.strptime(...)` que extrae la fecha desde el texto, con la siguiente línea de código podrías agregar la fecha dado tu formato:

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime('07-05-1990 12:30','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```